# Shopping List App-Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a student at Thinkful and I have a challenge where I need to create a shopping list app that will add, permanently remove, and check off items from a list using jquery. Here is my code so far and what I thought might work to delete the item but obviously it isn't. I am able to add items but not delete. Any help!!?

```js
//set the state
var state = {
 items: []
};
//function to modify the state
var addItem = function(state, item) {
 state.items.push(item);
}
var deleteItem = function(state, this) {
 state.this.remove(this);
}
//render the list
var renderList = function(state, element) {
 var itemsHTML = state.items.map(function(item) {
  return '<li><span class="shopping-item">' + item  +
  '</span><div class="shopping-item-controls">' + 
          '<button class="shopping-item-toggle">' +
            '<span class="button-label">check</span> </button>' +
          ' <button class="shopping-item-delete"><span class="button-label">delete</span>' +
          '</button> </div>';
 });
 element.html(itemsHTML);
};
//event listeners
$('.js-shopping-list-add').submit(function(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
 addItem(state, $('.js-shopping-list-add-input').val());
 renderList(state, $('.shopping-list'));
});
//delete item
$('.shopping-item-delete').click(function(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
 deleteItem();
});
```

```html
 <div class="container">
    <h1>Shopping List</h1>

    <form id="js-shopping-list-form" class="js-shopping-list-add">
      <label for="shopping-list-entry">Add an item</label>
      <input type="text" name="shopping-list-entry" id="shopping-list-entry" placeholder="e.g., broccoli" class="js-shopping-list-add-input">
      <button type="submit">Add item</button>
    </form>

    <ul class="shopping-list">
      <li>
        <span class="shopping-item">apples</span>
        <div class="shopping-item-controls">
          <button class="shopping-item-toggle">
            <span class="button-label">check</span>
          </button>
          <button class="shopping-item-delete">
            <span class="button-label">delete</span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </li>
```

Comment: first, in your `deleteItem` function, you wrote `state.this` instead of `state.items`

Answer (score 0):

change

```
var deleteItem = function(state, this) {
    state.this.remove(this);
}
```

to

```
var deleteItem = function(state, this) {
    state.items.remove(this);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't fully answer the question. Glancing at the Q, there are other problems with the code that prevent it from working. Also your answer/code isn't fully correct either in the context of the Q. Please edit and provide a complete answer and explanation.